# Gradle sync failing after attempting to import Parse project

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, gradle

I was following the Parse quickstart guide, downloaded their sample project, and opened it. There was a problem there, and now my previously working, non-Parse project is having trouble with Gradle. I'm getting the following problem every time I try to sync:

```
Error:(4, 0) Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist
```

I've been researching this online, and nothing I can find can even begin to help me. Any thoughts, at least on where to start? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: By request, here's my Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jpb9rq.cs2110.virginia.edu.chinupdemo"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: can you edit the question with the gradle file code?

Comment: Done - could this have anything to do with my target SDK being too low since I installed the 22 SDK tools?

Comment: This link might be helpful for you https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/8

Comment: Thanks - looked through that link a little earlier tonight. Right now, I'm not even worrying about importing Parse. I just want my original project back up and running.